# passing random variable to fp function

Tags: fp, esami

I am trying to create a command that will display a "+" sign for positive numbers and no sign for numbers within the esami package.  I believe that the issue is the format of the random variable that I am trying to pass into the \rtink function.  The function works if I use an integer, but I have been unable to figure out how to pass the variable through.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the problem that has been designed in the eachtest.tex file:

```
\newproblem{prob12
\FPsetpar{a}{1}{9}[-1,1]
\FPsetpar{b}{1}{9}[-1,1]

\newcommand{\rtink}[1]{%
\FPifneg #1 \par $$ \else $+$ \fi
}

\item  If 
\begin{equation*}  \a (x \rtink{\a} \b)=\a x+m \end{equation*} what is the value of $m$?

\vspace{10 mm}
  \begin{answers}{2}\bChoices
    \Ans1 \FPsv{\a*\b} \eAns
    \Ans0 \FPsv{-\a*\b} \eAns   \eFreeze
    \Ans0 \FPsv{\a} \eAns  \eFreeze
    \Ans0 \FPsv{\b} \eAns
    \eChoices\end{answers}
}
```

Here is the master_new.tex file that is pulling from the eachtest.tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[shufflerandom,xyz,twocolumns,solutions]{esami}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% +=============================+
% |         DEFINITIONS         |
% +=============================+

\def\examname{The name of the exam}
\def\numcompiti{1}%%% The number of the versions
\date{2013/3/22}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT YYYY/MM/DD
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading

\begin{document}
\testversioni
\pagestyle{esame}
\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers

% +=============================+
% |       THE SEED              |
% +=============================+

\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}

\randomi=\seme
\permuta

\section*{Mathematics Achievement}
\begin{test}
\begin{questions}
\esercizi{eachtest}
\end{questions}
\end{test}

\closevers
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, that `$$` looks suspicious. Shouldn't it be `\newcommand{\rtink}[1]{\FPifneg{#1}-\else+\fi}`?

Answer (score 4):

@egreg is surely right about the command. The correct definition of `\rtink` is

```
\newcommand{\rtink}[1]{\FPifneg{#1}-\else+\fi}
```

Moreover, your code contains some minor problems which can lead you to a result different from what you want.

1. `\newproblem{prob12`: The command `\newpbroblem` has only a mandatory argument, which is the text of the problem, which should begin after the `\FPsetpar` definitions. As it is constructed, `\newproblem` cannot accept things as labels or similar.
2. `\FPsetpar{a}{1}{9}[-1,1]`: you want here a parameter `\a` which assumes a random value between 1 and 9. You have excluded the values –1 and 1, but this is not necessary: the parameter is always different from –1, as it is greater or equal to 1, and to exclude the value 1 you can simply write `\FPsetpar{a}{2}{9}`. Moreover, excluded values must be in braces, inside the brackets, if they are more than one.
3. `\FPsv{\a*\b}`: even if usually you don't get an error, inside `\FPsv` it is better not to use `\a` and `\b`, but simply `a` and `b`, so your operation becomes `\FPsv{a*b}`
4. `\FPsv{\b}`: it is better to write `\b`, without `\FPsv`
5. the two `\eFreeze` in the second and third anwer are not necessary: as you have not used the optional parameter `[random]` after `\bChoices`, your answers won't shuffle.

Comment: Would you please add the correct definition of `\rtink` to your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. Done!

Comment: but for a negative number, when I display the equation in the line:'\begin{equation*}  \a (x \rtink{\a} \b)=\a x+m \end{equation*}', won't it display two negative signs if I change the definition of rtink?  I realize that in my earlier post I should have stated that.

Comment: @grames: I made the changes above, but I am still getting the following error: '! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...ink }[1]{\FPifneg {##1}-\else +\fi }
                                                   \par \item If \begin {equ...
l.17 }'

Comment: I have tried to compile your example. The command does not work if you put it in the exercise file. I have managed to make it work putting it in the esami.sty file, just after the definitions of `\FPsv` and `\sempli` (all variants). When you put it in the esami.sty file, your example works perfectly. Nevertheless, the code must be improved because there are some problems: the parametric version of the file cannot be obtained and, moreover, if the parameter \b is negative, you get a double - sign. We will see if there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: I just did the same, and it worked!  Even though the package has some issues, it is still pretty awesome.  Also, have you had a chance to look into my post under creating a list of random numbers using a loop?  I still haven't figured that out.

Comment: I have answered to the other post just now. Any feedback on the package and its issues will be greatly appreciated.